# save images from /zed/depth/depth_registered

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how i can save depth images as screenshot from topic save images from /zed/depth/depth_registered

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310000/save-images-from-/zed/depth/depth_registered/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi you can use [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) pkg and also pls see this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/9377/how-to-take-save-a-snapshot-from-my-kinect-to-disk/?answer=235294#post-id-235294)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0